# In 11-22-63, why Jake didn't bring high tech devices?

Tags: stephen-king, 11-22-63

In the *11-22-63* (TV series), Jack goes back in time to...

> prevent Kennedy's assassination

...to change the course of time.

But since he has such an easy way to go back in time, why doesn't he bring high-tech devices to spy on people? He could also bring a charging device to keep them working.

**Note:** I haven't read the book. If there are any references to this, please post them under a spoiler tag.

Comment: I don't this the basic premise of a show, which is apparent from the trailer, is a spoiler.   Plus, once you mention 'back in time', the date in the series title makes it pretty obvious what the premise is.

Comment: @ThePopMachine I'm not sure if that was for me but, the most spoilery thing in the series is not going back in the time.

Comment: I know -- the fact he goes back in time to do exactly what you put in the spoiler block is not a spoiler, IMO.  It's all over the media releases and trailer.

Comment: @ThePopMachine if I wouldn't put that under spoiler tag, someone would say something about putting it under a spoiler tag. If that bothers you so much...idk, can't do anything about it.

Comment: it doesn't -- just a comment.   No harm is done.

Comment: He's called Jake, not Jack.

Comment: @LightnessRaceinOrbit Yes,thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Specifically, he doesn't want to risk polluting the time-stream with unexpected changes from someone in the 60s finding incredibly advanced electronics and reverse-engineering them.

> He forgets and brings his cell phone with him, and disposes of it, as well as change with future dates, in a lake.

Also, the 60s were in the midst of the Cold War. Someone with unusual devices, particularly someone who lacks a good paper trail for his existence, might be suspected to be a Commie spy.

> And, in fact, Jack faces just that situation with the Secret Service in Dallas when they start exploring his history and find he has none.

Comment: The thing from your first spoiler: This happens in the series, too. And before getting rid of it, he uses it once to distract someone.